# Bug on English Language Learners

Tags: bug, login

I'm experiencing issues on English Language Learners.

Every time I visit ELL, I'm logged out. Then a screen with 'Welcome, pyraminx. You've been logged on. Click here to refresh" pops up at the top, but when I click the refresh button, the page refreshes but I'm still logged out.

I've tried manually clicking the reload button, manually clicking the sign in button and signing in, but after everything, it goes back to the main page without logging me in. Also, at every page (i.e. the log on page, the sign up page, etc) on the way, it tells me that I've been logged in, but every time it does the same thing.

I thought that maybe I was logged on, it just wasn't displaying it, but when I try to answer or post a comment, it tells me to sign up or log in.

I'm sure many other people have experienced this issue before. What could be the cause? The solution? Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I've tried it on every network. At first I just thought that this particular network wasn't working, but when I move to another place, the same things occur.

Comment: Now, the problem has expanded to all of the communities I'm currently in: physics, music, etc.

Comment: Clear browser cache, clear browser's local storage and try again.

Comment: Are you using Firefox?