# I can't sign up when I try to vote

Tags: bug, login, post-feedback

[image]

Clicking Sign up with Google or Facebook does not do anything. Clicking Sign up with Stack Exchange does work - it takes me to the new signup page:

```
site.stackexchange.com/users/signup
```

[image]

Here I can now chose to use a certain service to sign up, but it is quite annoying that I couldn't click it earlier.

I assume this is because of the (very nice) new login page.

It (interestingly) works if I click log in and then one of the 3 option - they all redirect to the new login page though, so it seems a little redundant.

Comment: Everything works for me.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't for me, and it bugs me a lot...

Comment: Any Javascript errors in the dev console in Chrome?

Comment: @Anna yes, `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) ... https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/users/login/global`. I assume somewhere still requests the old login page. That was before I even tried to login, just loading the page there.

Comment: -1 for useless rollbacks, if you want to test something we have the sandbox. (and 30 rollbacks? really??)

Comment: Closing this since that login UI is not in use at the moment. If/when we enable it across the network, I'll be sure to test that pop-up. If you are running into issues with the pop-up still, let me know. (P.S. Stop rolling back for no apparent reason. Thanks.)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me before, and my question has no answers yet: 
[bug on english language learners](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245518/bug-on-english-language-learners)

Though I don't know about the new logon page, I figured out the problem. When I tried another browser, I signed in.

Try reinstalling your browser or using another browser (like Firefox).

Comment: That is hardly a fitting answer, and your case sounds quite different than the one described here.

Comment: Reinstalling is unlikely to work on Ubuntu. It works on firefox but I'd like it to work on Google Chrome.